# R read.xlsx2 CountIf Imports as NA

Tags: r

I have an excel file with a `countif` column as below. Read.xlsx brings it in correctly, but read.xlsx2 brings in values as NA and blanks for blanks. What am I missing? Would really like to speed up performance with xlsx2

`Name   |CountIf Value    | Value
Andrew  |=COUNTIF(A:A,A2) |  2
Andrew  |=COUNTIF(A:A,A3) |  2
Bob     |=COUNTIF(A:A,A4) |  1`

Comment: Are you interested in maintaining the formula or are you just concerned with the result?

Comment: @MatthewCrews just the result

Comment: is this file a .xls or a .xlsx?

Comment: Are you sure the formulas are correct in the CountIf column? That seems to be a strange range pattern with always looking at column A but having the matches go across the rows.

Comment: xlsm file. and I mistyped - I fixed the formulas to go down

Comment: I tried with xlsx and same thing happens so don't think it is the file format

Comment: Please state the package you use in the Question. (I'm assuming it's `xlsx`.)

Comment: @snaut Yes I am using xlsx via the `read.xlsx2` command